# How to build custom PLINQO query by multiple id's?

Tags: sql, linq, plinqo

Here's my table structure

**Places**

- PlaceId PK
- Name
- ...

**PlaceCategories**

- CatId PK
- Name
- ...

**PlaceCats**

- PlaceId PK
- CatId PK

Here's my query that pulls Places based on category id (table join)

```
public static IQueryable<Places> ByPlaceCat(this Table<Places> table, Expression<Func<PlaceCats, bool>> predicate) {
    var db = (DataContext)table.Context;
    var innerBizBase = db.PlaceCats.Where(predicate);
    return db.Places.Join(innerBizBase, a => a.PlaceId, ab => ab.PlaceId, (a, ab) => a);
}
```

I use it like this:

```
places = Db.Places.ByPlaceCat(a => a.CatId == 5);
```

But I want to be able to pull based on a `List<int>` of category id's. Looking through the generated PLINQO code, a query that pulls by multiple PlaceId's (but not using a joined table) looks like this:

```
public static IQueryable<Places> ByPlaceId(this IQueryable<Places> queryable, IEnumerable<long> values)
{
    return queryable.Where(p => values.Contains(p.PlaceId));
}
```

How could I essentially merge those two queries, to let me pass in a `List<int>` of CatId's to query by? This LINQ/PLINQO query is melting my brain. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to write a extension method like this:

```
    public static IQueryable<Places> ByPlaceCats(this Table<Places> table, IEnumerable<int> catIds)
    {
        var db = (TestDataContext)table.Context;
        var places = (from placeCat in db.PlaceCats
                      join place in db.Places on placeCat.PlaceId equals place.PlaceId
                      where catIds.Contains(placeCat.CatId)
                      select place);
        return places;
    }
```

Please note that the PlaceCats table could be made into a [ManyToMany relationship](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks/plinqo/tour/manytomany) by adding two foreign keys to the proper tables. Once this change has been made than [PLINQO](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks/plinqo/) will automatically generate the correct code and will create a link between the two tables skipping the intermediary table. So you could get a collection of PlaceCategories associated to the current Places entity by accessing a property on the Places entity.

Please remember to [contact us](http://www.codesmithtools.com/contactus) if you have any questions and be sure to check out the community forums located [here](http://community.codesmithtools.com/) and [PLINQO forums here](http://community.codesmithtools.com/Template_Frameworks/f/66.aspx).

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (CodeSmith Support)

Comment: Aye, PlaceCats is the join table. I downloaded the latest PLINQO templates and regenerated the code. The many-to-many relations are there. I asked this for this scenario: I need to list places that are in every sub-category of a parent category, assuming the PlaceCats table does not have an entry joining parent categories to places.

Comment: I've since changed my design, I'll simply assign parent categories to places in the PlaceCats table too... no need for the query. But I REALLY appreciate the quick response, and I'll still put this query into my code for later use. Much appreciated.